# Conditionals in numpy. How can i put 3 or more into my dataframe using pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have trouble with my syntax. I want to buy when the LastPrice will be > to the lower band and sell when the LastPrice == sma level, if this os true, i want to put the result into a column as: "Buy" it is not like this put "Sell"

My Code:

```
df['LastPrice'].dropna(inplace=True)
sma = df['LastPrice'].rolling(window=20).mean()
rstd = df['LastPrice'].rolling(window=20).std()
df['upper_band'] = sma + 2 * rstd
df['lower_band'] = sma - 2 * rstd
df['laseñalota'] = np.where((df['LastPrice'] > df['lower_band'],"Buy") & (df['LastPrice'] == sma), "Sell")
```

The error is:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (4508,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['laseñalota'] = np.where(df['LastPrice'] > df['lower_band'], 'Buy', 
    np.where(df['LastPrice'] <= sma, 'Sell', 'Do Nothing'))
```

As per @user3483203's suggestion, it is also possible to use `np.select` if you have more conditions and want to more accurately reflect it in a separate line in the code. See below code for example:

```
condlist = [df['LastPrice'] > df['lower_band'], df['LastPrice'] <= sma]
choicelist = ['Buy', 'Sell']
df['new_laseñalota'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Comment: You don't need to chain `numpy.where` calls here, there are only two options.  If you are going to have *more* than two options, use `numpy.select` instead